# Encabezados laterales en tablas

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

¿Cómo puedo crear encabezados laterales izquierdo en tablas? Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Titulo 1</th>
            <th>Titulo 2</th>
            <th>Titulo 3</th>
            <th>Titulo 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody style="background: #bdbdbd;">
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody style="background: #bdbdbd;">
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
            <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

y asi se veria en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver tengo seccionados los `tbody` por color ya que debe ser así, yo quiero agregarle una cabecera extra de lado izquierdo a cada uno de esos `tbody` para indicar la separación, algo así como unas pestañas

**Nota:** He probado con rowspan y la idea es que no estén dentro de la tabla, si no a un lado, como pestañas.

¿como hago eso? ¡¡Gracias!!

Comment: como recomendación, solo deberías tener un tbody. Por el lado de la pregunta. A ver si está claro ¿Quieres una celda que englobe a cada tbody(cada 3 celdas) para mostrar un nombre para ese segmento?

Comment: @ReneLimon, gracias por responder, no tanto una celda, si no algo como una pestaña ( como la de los navegadores pero en lateral izquierdo ) por cada tbody, y no por cada 3 celdas ya que estas son dinamicas.

Comment: @amenadiel Como reparo la inserción de la imagen ? y que es eso? no entiendo :)

Comment: @ReneLimon no hay nada de malo en usar varios tbody. La especificación indica que a diferencia de thead y tfoot, pueden haber muchos tbody. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#Usage_notes

Comment: @IranhCanulMay no estoy seguro. Algo había quedado mal en el markdown así que la inserté de nuevo. Mi nota de edición dice lo que cambió: "repara inserción de imagen"

Comment: @IranhCanulMay no te sirve la respuesta de Rene?, **crees que puedas hacer una imagen de lo que realmente esperas**, esto lo digo porque para mi la respuesta de Rene simula o hace lo que pides, solo es cuestión de ajustar el código a como esperas

Comment: @JuankGlezz en parte necesito que sean en tbody ( ya que cada tbody repesenta una sección que puede tener registros variados los tbody son mas facil seccionarlos ) y claro, haré una imagen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta la primer recomendación que hice (solo deberías tener un tbody), podrias solo estilizar la primer celda para dar forma de pestañas:

```css
td, th{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.pestana{
  background-color: #DFD;
  color: black;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  min-width:20px;
  border-left: 0px;
}

thead .pestana{
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="pestana"></th>
      <th>Titulo 1</th>
      <th>Titulo 2</th>
      <th>Titulo 3</th>
      <th>Titulo 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- primer segmento -->
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" class="pestana">Head 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
    </tr>
    
    <!-- segundo segmento -->
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" class="pestana">Head 2</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ejemplo 1</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 2</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 3</td>
      <td>Ejemplo 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

donde `rowspan="3"` es un numero variable dependiendo el numero por el cual se desea agrupar.

Comment: Es interesante pero el primer cuadro verde con (*) dentro no me sirve, y he estado tratando de ajustarlo pero no me queda, me serviria mucho si se usan los tbody

Comment: @IranhCanulMay he modificado el código. Lo tbody los puede seguir usando y no afecta este código, solo me parece redundante usar muchos tbodys

Comment: Si, esto es lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!

Comment: excelente, solo recuerda que si el texto vertical no se ajusta correctamente solo aumenta el min-width